# Modifying lists and environments

Tags: r, list, function, environment

I am reading Hadley Wickham advanced R on environments. [Here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#explicit-envs) it mentions:

> Unlike most objects in R, when you modify an environment, it does not
>   make a copy. For example, look at this modify() function.

```
modify <- function(x) {
  x$a <- 2
  invisible()
}
```

> If you apply it to a list, the original list is not changed because
>   modifying a list actually creates and modifies a copy.

```
x_l <- list()
x_l$a <- 1
modify(x_l)
x_l$a
## [1] 1
```

> However, if you apply it to an environment, the original environment
>   is modified:

```
x_e <- new.env()
x_e$a <- 1
modify(x_e)
x_e$a
## [1] 2
```

What does it mean that modifying a list creates and modifies a copy? I see that after applying `modify(x_l)`, I would assume the object to which `x_l` points to has been modified. However, it hasn't (`x_l$a` is still 1). What is happening under the hood for the list not being updated by the modify function?

Comment: Mostly just what the book says: the function creates a copy of `x_l`, modifies that copy, but the version in the global environment remains unchanged. Any object in the function that is not returned or explicitly assigned in a different scope will be just discarded once the function has exited.

Comment: @joran So the `modify` function creates a copy for its function execution environment, makes modifications on that copy and then the copy is deleted as the function ends (unless the function has a return at the end,right?). Thanks, it is simple but I wasn't understanding it. :-/

Comment: Yes, generally. There are ways (`assign`, eg) to create a variable assignment in an arbitrary environment that side steps this sort of thing, but they are rarely used (and frowned upon) in R. The simple rule of thumb is that things you do in a function only exist in that function's scope, unless returned. The book is saying that environments are an exception to that general rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a list is modified then a new list is created (and an object that is created in a function is local to that function and is removed when the function exits).  Note the computations below involving `L1` and that the address of `L1` has changed after it is modified.

On the other hand an environment has an identity distinct from its contents.  Changing the contents of an environment does not change the environment's identity. Note that after we modified the contents of the environment `e1` that its address did not change.

```
library(pryr)

L1 <- list(a = 1)
address(L1)
## [1] "0xdb8aeb0"
L1$b <- 2
address(L1)
## [1] "0x841eca8"

e1 <- list2env(L1)
address(e1)
## [1] "0xbdf2420"
e1$c <- 3
address(e1)
## [1] "0xbdf2420"
```

Comment: And I guess list `L1` stored in address `0xdb8aeb0` is deleted automatically as the new modified `L1` is created in address `0x841eca8`, right?

Comment: The original `L1` would no longer be user accessible and its storage would be freed upon the next instance of garbage collection at least conceptually.  If this were done in a function then the storage for the new `L1` would become inaccessible when the function exits (provided you don't pass the environment within the function out) and freed upon garbage collection.